# Can builds from the same source code yield functionally different executables?

Tags: java, android, build

Recently, a colleague of mine said something along these lines: "consecutive APKs (executables) produced by build server from the same source code might not be the same". The context for this discussion was whether QA performed on build X also applies to build Y, which was performed by the same build server (configured the same way) from the same source code.

I think that generated executables might not be identical due to various factors (e.g. different timestamp), but the question is whether they can be *functionally* different.

The only scenario, that I can think of, in which the same source code could produce different functionality is that of multi-threading issue: in case of incorrect synchronization of multi-threaded code, different re-ordering/optimization actions performed at compile time could affect this poorly synchronized code and change its functional behavior.

My questions are:

1. Is it true that consecutive builds performed by the same build server from the same source code can be functionally different?
2. If #1 is true, are these differences limited to incorrectly synchronized multi-threaded code?
3. If #2 is false, what are the other parts that can change?

Links to any related material will be appreciated.

Comment: Usually, the generated byte code is the _same_ if the same build tool in the same version is used to build the same source code. Unless ... well, unless you are doing some tricks like putting some build timestamp into some metafile which gets generated and packed into the resulting JAR and you also read that metafile with your code doing something else on a particular timestamp.

Comment: I have to admit to be a layman in the issue and hence could very gravely err and misunderstand. But my simplistic logical thinking is this: If a source code could at build time process a timestamp, why couldn't it at certain branches of the code check whether the time is earlier or later than a predetermined one and cause the builder do different things according to the outcomes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly possible in a few cases.  I'll assume you are using Gradle to build your Android app.

**Case 1:** You are using a 3rd party dependency that's included with a version wildcard, such as:

`compile somelib.1+`

It's possible for the dependency to change in this case, which is why it's highly recommended to use explicit dependency versions.

**Case 2:** You're injecting environment information into your app using Gradle's buildConfigFields.  These values will be injected into your app's `BuildConfig` class.  Depending on how you use those values, the app behavior could vary on consecutive builds.

**Case 3:** You update the JDK on your CI in-between consecutive builds.  It's possible, though I'd assume highly unlikely, that your app behavior could change depending on how it's compiled.  For example, you might be hitting an edge case in the JDK that gets fixed in a later version, causing code that previously worked before to act differently.

I think this answers your first question and second question.

edit: sorry, I think I missed some important info from your OP.  My case 2 is an example of your `e.g. different timestamp` and case 3 violates your `configured the same way`.  I'll leave the answer here though.

Answer (score 5):

I think that different functionality may be caused only by discrepancies in environment or maybe you are using snapshot version of some 3rd party library, and thus it was updated after some time.

some advice:
if it possible to rebuild it, use verbose mode of build tool (-X in maven for example) and compare output line by line with some diff program

Answer (score 4):

If the same source code could produce different results on the same machine / configuration, programming as we know it would probably not be possible.

There is always an option that things break, when the language level, operating system, or some other dependency changes. If all that changes it the time of the build, you would have to do *something fundamentally wrong*.

Using android / gradle, one possible reason to lead to a different behavior or errors in general is using `+` in your `build.gradle` file for library versions. This is why you should avoid doing so, since a consecutive build could fetch a newer / different version, hence you'd have different source code, and thus it could create a functional different executable.

A good build should always be *repeatable*. This means given the same configuration it should have the same results. If it isn't, you could never rely on anything and would have to do total regression testing on everything.

> [...] consecutive builds performed by the same build server from the same source code can be functionally different

No. As described above, if you use the same versions, the same source code, it should produce the same behavior. Unless you do something very wrong.

> [...] are these differences limited to incorrectly synchronized multi-threaded code?

This would imply a bug with your compiler. While this is possible, it is extremely unlikely.

> [...] what are the other parts that can change?

Besides the timestamp and the build number nothing else *should* change, given the same source code and configuration.

---

It is always a good idea to include unit (and other) tests in your build. This way you can test specific behavior to be the same with each build.

Comment: "Besides the timestamp and the build number nothing else should change" -> I don't know whether this applies to the compilers you are using, but for other compilers, it certainly doesn't apply. For example, the C# compiler by design includes a GUID in every new binary, to make them different; and GCC can (could?) choose (randomly) different optimizations in different runs. See https://superuser.com/questions/639351/does-recompiling-a-program-produce-a-bit-for-bit-identical-binary

Comment: @hmijail this question is about java and android, though. Maybe there are some, I would not know of any. Also I think it is fair to assume that the GUID and build number are quite similar since both change with every build

Answer (score 1):

They should be identical,except:

- there is threading/optimization issues in build system.
- hardware failures CPU/RAM/HDD issues on build environment
- time/platform related code in build system itself or build scripts

So if you are building exact same code on exact same HW using exact same version of build system, same OS version and your code DO NOT SPECIALLY DEPEND from build time result **should be same**. They even should have exact same check sums and size.

Also **results is same ONLY if your code do not depend on external modules which is downloaded from Internet** at build time like Gradle/Maven does - you can't grantee this libraries the same because of they are not in version control. Moreover there is can be dependency where module version specified not exactly (like 2.0.+) so if maintainer updated this module your build system will use updated one -> so basically your builds generated from different source code.

As somebody mention using Unit tests on build server is good practice to make sure your build is stable and don't contain obvious bugs.

Answer (score 0):

While this question addresses Java/Android, Jon Skeet blogged about [different C# parsers treating some Unicode characters differently](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/12/01/when-is-an-identifier-not-an-identifier-attack-of-the-mongolian-vowel-separator/), mostly due to changes in the Unicode character database.

In his examples, the *Mongolian Vowel Separator (U+180E)* is considered either a whitespace character or a character allowed within an identifier, yielding different results in variable assignments.

Answer (score -1):

It is definately possible. You can construct an example program that will behave different in functionality everytime you start it up.

Imagine a strategy design pattern that lets you choose between algorithms during runtime and you load one algorithm based on RNG.

Comment: That's not different than producing a different code. In your example the code is meant to behave in different way any time you start it, regardless of the build.